# How do I detect if the user touched my Sprites/screen?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch, spawning

Basically, the sprite is spawned at a random time every (1,2 or 3 sec) and infinitely. I  want the sprite to disappear once it's touched on the screen. (android touch event)

```
public void newEnemy(){
        Sprite newEnemy=Pools.obtain(Sprite.class);
        newEnemy.set(enemy);
        newEnemy.setPosition(200, 700);
        enemies.add(newEnemy);
    }

public void update(){
        deltaTime=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        timer+=1*deltaTime;
        timer2+=1*deltaTime;
        timer3+=1*deltaTime;

        if(timer>=random){
            newEnemy();  //spawn a new enemy
            timer-=random;
            random=rTime.nextInt(3)*1f+1;//create random time if timer>= initial random time;
        }
```

Comment: Are you checking if one sprite touched another sprite or something else like the mouse?

Comment: I'm making an android game I wan't to detect if the user touched the sprite/screen.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up a touch listener. Information on that [here](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html)

You will then need to check if the touch location is within your sprite bounds.
A common way to do this would be to create a rectangle and check if the touch location is inside of the rectangle like this

```
 Rectangle2D bounds = new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);

`if(bounds.contains(`the touch x value`,` the touch y value`){`

         //your code to remove the sprite
    }
```

Alternately you could write your own method in sprite, this would be a better decision if all you needed was the contains method. That way, you don't have to import another library. **(Note that it doesn't make much of a difference but it's good practice)**

```
public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
     return (x > this.x && y > this.y && x < this.x + this.width && y < this.y + this.height);
}
```

Comment: can i just use normal rectangles cause I'm using them for collision detection. Btw I'm using libgdx

Comment: Yes, you could also just have your sprite include the four variables `x` `y` `width` `height` and write your own method.